# How to move file to different folder in same bucket aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, bucket, mv

I have a small question, I'm trying to move one specific file from one folder to another in the same bucket, the name of the file is stored in a variable. In fact, when executing this command, the name of the file is not read correctly. here is the example:

```
    times = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S") 
    name="test1" 
    if "test" in name: 
        cmd='aws s3 mv s3://bucket_name/folder/folder1/"$name" 
         s3://bucket_name/folder/folder2/"$name_$times"'
        proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE) 
        try:
           outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15) 
        except TimeoutExpired: 
           proc.kill() outs, errs = proc.communicate()**
```

result: the file does not move

But when I use:

```
    cmd='aws s3 mv s3://bucket_name/folder/folder1/test1 
     s3://bucket_name/folder/folder2/test1_2021'
```

the file is moved.

I'd like to know if there is a way to read the name of the variable in the command line, thank you!

Comment: #python #commandline

Answer (score 0):

Python String interpolation doesn't work like this. You need (Python 3.6 and higher)

```
cmd=f'aws s3 mv s3://bucket_name/folder/folder1/{name} s3://bucket_name/folder/folder2/{name}_{times}'
```

Also times isn't properly formatted. It will create something like `'2021/11/02-14:36:02'`, which can't be part of a filename.

You can use [input](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#input) to read the name of the variable.

And I strongly recommend to use boto3 instead of creating a process to call the AWS CLI.